# add menu items to an Context Menu in a Brackets extension

Tags: adobe-brackets

I'm trying to add a menu with sub menu items to the editor context menu. I can create the main menu item, but it fails when I try to add items.

> Exception is "addMenuItem is not a function".

The documentation mentions SubMenu, but the doc's are not the best with few samples.

```
function loadSnippets() {
    var config = JSON.parse(require("text!./config.json"));
    var editorMenu, mainMenu;

    CommandManager.register("Easy Snippets", ID, doMainMenu);

    editorMenu = Menus.getContextMenu(Menus.ContextMenuIds.EDITOR_MENU);
    editorMenu.addMenuDivider();
    mainMenu = editorMenu.addMenuItem(ID, "Ctrl-Shift-K");    

    config.Snippets.forEach(function (item) {
        var itemID = ID + "-" + item.Name.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "-");
        CommandManager.register(item.Name, itemID, doItemSelected);

        mainMenu.addMenuItem(itemID);
    });
};
```